# Save an array of models in rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, models

I have an array that keeps some instances of a model (SupplierPhone) like this:

```
supplier_phone = SupplierPhone.where(:supplier_id => 1)
supplier_phone =  [#<SupplierPhone id: 1, supplier_id: 1, phone: "22423434234",
created_at: "2011-07-21 00:56:26", updated_at: "2011-07-21 00:56:26">, 
#<SupplierPhone id: 2, supplier_id: 1, phone: "98776234423", 
 created_at: "2011-07-21 00:56:27", updated_at: "2011-07-21 00:56:27">]
```

I want to save each element of the array supplier_phone in a new instance of SupplierPhone, can somebody tell me how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
supplier_phone.each{ |sp| SuplierPhone.create(sp.attributes) }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use associations. **supplier has_many :phones"**, then get the phones through a chain "supplier.phones"